# Add dynamic Radiobutton into RadioGroup

Tags: android

```
public class MCQSample extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView title;
    String gotBread;
    RadioGroup AnswerRG;
    int value ;
    int value1;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mcqsample); 
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);
        nextP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextP);
        backP = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backP);
        AnswerRG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.AnswerRG);


            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            value = b.getInt("key", 0);

        }
    }
```

Hi guys, im doing the Android app and stuck on create the dynamic radio-button. Because i don't know how many button i need (which depend on the value - user input). I read some posts which can add on the Layout but i want to add into the radioGroup. Is there any ways? Thank

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.

Comment: Do not define your Radio buttons in XML layout, define them programically.

Comment: nice but can we add RadioButton and one TextEdit in one horizontal line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step #1: Create a new `RadioButton` via its constructor and configure it as you see fit.

Step #2: Call `addView()` on your `RadioGroup` to add the `RadioButton` to it.

Step #3: There is no step #3

Comment: isn't Step #3 supposed to be "Profit"?

Comment: @MikeIsrael: That would require Step #N-1 to be "???". I'm going old-school with a Matrix "there is no spoon" approach. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way we can add the radio and a TextEdit in a same horizontal Line? :-s

Comment: @CaoLinhTruong: I am not sure. It used to be that a `RadioButton` had to be an immediate child of `RadioGroup` for the `RadioGroup` to work. And, to achieve your desired effect, you would have to have the `RadioButton` and `EditText` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` inside the `RadioGroup`. You are welcome to give it a try, but if the `RadioButton` no longer responds as part of the group, then the old limitation is still in force.

Comment: hm it's force close!! anyway tks.

Answer (score 3):

try this way to add radiobutton in `RadioGroup`:

```
private final int WC = RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
RadioGroup.LayoutParams rParams;
AnswerRG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.AnswerRG);

RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
radioButton.setText("Yellow");
radioButton.setId(1001);//set radiobutton id and store it somewhere
rParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(WC, WC);
AnswerRG.addView(radioButton, rParams);
```

Comment: Nice! Can add Id also.^^ Tks bro. Is there any way we can add the radio and a TextEdit in a same horizontal Line?

Comment: if you want to add TextEdit  in RadioGroup i think it's not possible.i'm not confirm  but you can try it in same as we are adding RadioButton